# Missing certain @helpers in Views ASP.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model

I'm having an excessively strange issue.

I'm working on a project and it's being converted to use asp.net MVC.

Everything works the controllers/models/views. I get every keyword possible in the controller (ViewBag, ViewContext, etc.).

In my views, however, I only get some helpers (e.g. @Model, @Html), but I'm missing others (@model, @ViewBag, @ViewContext, etc.)

It's an enormous hinderance (i'd post code but I don't know what code is really relevant). My web.config is 100% dead-on and all of my other MVC projects do not have this issue.

- Web.Config is correct(in the Views folder)
- Target framework is correct
- I have access to all of the methods in my controllers

I've cleaned the project/re-mapped it, etc. Others on other machines do not have this issue, but oddly I do (I've entirely re-checked out the project).

Like I said, i don't know what code is relevant I'm just hoping someone else has an idea as what can be wrong. I'm baffled since the web.config is right, i'm not missing any references (all my references are pointing to the correct location), and I can use all of them in the controller.

Just because I don't want to get yelled at, here's an excerpt from my web.config in the Views/ folder

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

One of the strangest issues i've ever experienced :O

**Sample:**

```
@model Project.WebUI.Models.MyModel

@{
    ViewBag.title = "hi";
}

<div>@Model.someItemInTheModel</div>
```

**model is red underlined 'does not exist in current context'**

```
@model Project.WebUI.Models.MyModel
```

**ViewBag is red underlined 'does not exist in current context'**

```
ViewBag.title = "hi";
```

**This line is perfectly fine**

```
<div>@Model.someItemInTheModel</div>
```

**Controller, this is all perfectly fine**

```
public ActionResult MyView(long date)
{
   MyModel model = new MyModel();
   model.someItemInTheModel = "hi";
   return PartialView(model);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "In my views, however, I only get some keywords".  What does it mean to "get keywords"?

Comment: helpers, is what i meant as in the title.

Comment: By "getting keywords", do you mean autocomplete?

Comment: @bbedward, that did not help at all.  What do you *mean* by "getting"?   As jrummell asks, are you referring to autocomplete?

Comment: @KirkWoll No, I can't use certain helpers in my views. Not autocomplete, I actually can't use them I get the visual studio red underline of death. In my controllers everything is fine, only in the views. But I am not missing all of them only some (model, ViewBag, ViewContext), I can use others like (Html, Model)

Comment: Do you get a compilation error?

Comment: @jrummell No, which is really odd. I get runtime errors when trying to reference something from the model?

Comment: @bbedward, then jrummell is probably right, and that you have some mismatch in one of your web.config files.  However, can you post a screen capture of the editor with the squigglies?  Or at least post some sample code and show us what gets squigglied?

Comment: @bbedward what are the runtime errors?

Comment: Have you been able to find out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new MVC3 project and compare those web.config files to the ones in your project. You'll need the check the in the project root (`/web.config`) and in `/Views/web.config`.

Also check to make sure you have all of the same `System.Web.*` references.

Comment: Like i said though, it's a perfect match and I do get certain helpers like @Model, but not model or ViewBag, ViewContext, etc. The web.configs are a match and i have all the references (IE I can use them all in my controller)

Comment: Ack!  What do you mean by "getting helpers"?  I literally cannot parse that at all.  Please explain yourself.  Helpers are not something to "get" -- they are something you define.

Comment: I'm going to accept this. It says 'does not exist in current context' which is baffling to me and annoying, but the runtime issue was caused by something else. Still have no idea why it doesn't think they exist but it's ok at runtime so.. :?

Comment: Sometimes a clean/rebuild gets rid of the red squiglies ... if you're using ReSharper, it might be worth clearing it cache as well.